# Can't get '~' using shift-` but shift-\ gives tilde

Tags: keyboard

Also when I try to get the pipe command `|` using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> it gives me a tilde '~'. I've tried a different keyboard and those are the only 2 mis-mappings I see.

Comment: What distro are you using and what language is your keyboard? If you are using Raspbian then you can remap the keyboard using sudo raspi-config will include a menu item to remap the keyboard.

Comment: I was able to ssh into the pi and don't have this problem, so its not a big deal since I will be mostly using it remotely.

Comment: The fact that it works as expected when you SSH in to the box means that the language and keyboard settings are correct on the machine you are SSHing from. You can check the settings and appl;y them to your Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem a while back, your keyboard language is set to United Kingdom/British instead of USA/United States.

Comment: bloody roight, mate! I went into the internationalization section and set it back.